# setComponentStyle doesn't work in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, cs4

I have a list component in the main timeline of my movie and...

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.color = xmlData.config.playList.@textColor;
StyleManager.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
```

the code above works fine but why doesn't this work?

```
StyleManager.setComponentStyle(List, "textFormat", tf);
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this looks like it may be a bug specifically targeting the `TextFormat` of the `List` component. 

I ran a test where I called `StyleManager.setComponentStyle(Button, "textFormat", tf)` and it worked. 

I ran another test where I called `StyleManager.setComponentStyle(List, "contentPadding", 30)` and it worked as expected.

Comment: @Marcela Yes but : StyleManager.setComponentStyle(List, "textFormat", tf) doesn't work. You set in 2nd argument a global `style property` "contentPadding" which value is '30' instead of setting a global `textFormat` which name is 'tf'.

Answer (score 0):

The [CellRenderer class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/listClasses/CellRenderer.html) is adapted.

> The CellRenderer class defines methods and properties for list-based
>   components to use to manipulate and display custom cell content in
>   each of their rows. A customized cell can contain text, an existing
>   component such as a CheckBox, or any class that you create. The
>   list-based components that use this class include the List, DataGrid,
>   TileList, and ComboBox components.

**CustomCellRenderer.as**

You have first created a class named `CustomCellRenderer` (File > New > ActionSript File).

```
package com 
{
    import fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class CustomCellRenderer extends CellRenderer
    {
        public function CustomCellRenderer()
        {
            setStyle("textFormat", new TextFormat("arial", 10, 0xFF00FF));
        }
    }
}
```

**myFla.fla**

If you want to apply your textFormat to the instance myList of the class List:

```
import com.CustomCellRenderer;

myList.setStyle("cellRenderer", CustomCellRenderer);
```

If you want to apply your textFormat to all the instances of the class List:

```
import com.CustomCellRenderer;
import fl.managers.StyleManager;

StyleManager.setComponentStyle(List, "cellRenderer", CustomCellRenderer);
```

Adobe help about [CellRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fd4.html).

Comment: But how can I then get the color definition from a parameters file?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. These class and package things are new to me. I tried your example but got errors when compiling.

Comment: Now I got a compilation without errors but the next commands are not working:

Comment: mp3List.setStyle("cellRenderer", listText);
    StyleManager.setComponentStyle(List, "cellRenderer", listText);
 StyleManager.setStyle("cellRenderer", listText);